# Foreign key or link between part of column selection

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, indexing, foreign-key-relationship, create-table

I have 3 tables in the following setup

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[codevariable] (
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [code] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [variable] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[proxy] (
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [status] [bit] NULL,
    [added] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[wall] (
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Following values in the tables
Table Wall

```
1   This is a basic wall
2   This is a medium wall
3   This is an advanced wall
```

Table Proxy

```
1   Small Proxy True    2013-05-08 00:00:00.000
2   Medium Proxy    False   2013-05-08 00:00:00.000
```

Table CodeVariable

```
1   Proxy       1         
2   Proxy       2         
3   Wall        1         
4   Wall        2         
5   Wall        3
```

Owke now the issue that i am facing, if i want to insert lets say a new line in proxy. Then it will have Id 3, now i need to make sure that id 3 also exists in CodeVariable under the code Proxy!

Without foreign key there is no check if the code exists in code variable.

I have tried with foreign keys but without success. How can i create a link between the CodeVariable table on the columns code and variable towards table proxy and table wall.

I can also created index on Code and variable that is unique. but u cannot link a foreign key to it.

I am using SQL 2008

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can link a FK to composite unique.  But you have to link to the whole key.  And the types need to be the same.  And why is Wall even in the question?

Comment: Does this mean i have to add in the proxy and the wall table additional columns? This means that the howl column will have the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to change the table definitions, so `FOREIGN KEY` constraints can be enforced.

Use a composite primary key `(codeid, codetype)` for table `codevariable` (renamed `code`), where `codetype` can take only 2 possible values, either `'P'` or `'W'`.
(The `code` you had could be used instead of the `codetype` but I preferred a narrower column as keys (primary and foreign) are used in indexes.
 The `code` was converted to a computed column):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[code] (
    [codeid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [codetype] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [codename] AS                               -- computed column
         CASE codetype WHEN 'P' THEN 'Proxy'
                       WHEN 'W' THEN 'Wall'
         END,
    CONSTRAINT code_PK
        PRIMARY KEY (codeid, codetype),
    CONSTRAINT codetype_CK
        CHECK (codetype IN ('P', 'W'))
) ;
```

In the two other tables, the `codetype` was added as well, so the `(codeid, codetype)` can be defined as both `PRIMARY` and `FOREIGN` key:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[proxy] (
    [proxyid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [codetype] [char](1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'P',
    [description] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [status] [bit] NULL,
    [added] [datetime] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT proxy_PK
        PRIMARY KEY (proxyid, codetype),
    CONSTRAINT code_proxy_FK
        FOREIGN KEY (proxyid, codetype)
        REFERENCES code (codeid, codetype),
    CONSTRAINT codetype_proxy_CK
        CHECK (codetype = 'P')
) ;


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[wall] (
    [wallid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [codetype] [char](1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'W',
    [description] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT wall_PK
        PRIMARY KEY (wallid, codetype),
    CONSTRAINT code_wall_FK
        FOREIGN KEY (wallid, codetype)
        REFERENCES code (codeid, codetype),
    CONSTRAINT codetype_wall_CK
        CHECK (codetype = 'W')
) ;
```

**[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef93d)**